# equivalent characterizations of differentiability of maps between smooth manifolds (a la Warner)

Tags: differential-geometry, derivatives, smooth-manifolds

I have been trying to supply the details for why two different definitions of differentiability for continuous maps $\psi:M\to N $ between smooth manifolds are equivalent. Here are some background definitions, just so that we're on the same page:

> Let $U \subset M$ be open. A map $f:U\to R$ is a smooth function on U if $f\circ \phi^{-1} (:im(\phi)\to \mathbb{R})$ is smooth for each coordinate map $\phi$ on open sets of $M$.
>
> A continuous map $\psi:M\to N$ is differentiable if $g\circ\psi\ (:M\to \mathbb{R})$ is a smooth function on $\psi^{-1}(dom(g))$ for all smooth functions $g$ defined on open sets in $N$.

That's from Warner. Then he claims that $\psi$ is differentiable if and only if $\phi\circ\psi\circ\tau^{-1} (:\mathbb{R^d}\to\mathbb{R^n})$ is smooth for each coordinate map $\tau$ on open sets of $M$ and $\phi$ on open sets of $N$.

My attempt at a proof is as follows:

> ($\Rightarrow$) If $\psi\in C^{\infty}(M,N)$, then $g\circ\psi$ is $C^{\infty}$ for every smooth function $g$ defined on open sets of $N$. Since $g\circ\psi:M\to \mathbb{R}$ is a smooth function, $g\circ\psi\circ\tau^{-1}$ is $C^{\infty}$ for each coordinate function $\tau$ on open sets of $M$. Then,
>
> $g\circ\psi\circ\tau^{-1} = g\circ(\phi^{-1}\circ\phi)\circ\psi\circ\tau^{-1}  
> = (g\circ\phi^{-1})\circ(\phi\circ\psi\circ\tau^{-1})$

and we know that $g\circ\phi^{-1}$ is smooth because $g$ is a smooth function. At this point, I can come up with a counterexample that tells me I can't get the conclusion I'm clearly trying to obtain.

Is there a different route to this? I think I've been staring for so long that I'm having trouble seeing my other options.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning is good. The difficulty you're mentioning, I'm assuming that it is that if a composition is smooth, the functions might not be smooth separately. What you have to take into account in this case, is that you assumed it was smooth for every single function $g$. Argue by contradiction. Assume that $\phi\circ \psi \circ \tau^{-1}$ is not smooth, you should try to show that there is a smooth function $g$ for which the composition $g\circ \psi \circ \tau^{-1}$ is not smooth; this contradicts your previous conclusion.

Comment: Thank you, I like this method. I believe one may also prove this directly by looking at the canonical coordinate maps sending an n-tuple to its ith coordinate and checking smoothness there.

Comment: Well, that is essentially what you have to do, yes